# Using UrlEncode in HyperLink Button in .NET and in Anchor Tag of HTML

Tags: c#, .net

I am just trying to use UrlEncode in a Hyperlink which is in GridView and found it was not working. Then I tried to take the HyperLink as a separate control and tried with that. It is not giving Hyperlink to me, I mean it is not even clickable.

While when I tried with simple Anchor tag, it is working. This is what I am using

```
    <asp:HyperLink   ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl ='<%= "~/Default.aspx?customer=" + "&CompanyName=" + Server.UrlEncode("abc#")%>' > wc  
    </asp:HyperLink>

// While following is working
    <a  title="asxd" href='<%= "~/Default.aspx?customer=" + "&CompanyName=" + Server.UrlEncode("abc#")%>'>wc
</a>
```

Still looking for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `Hyperlink` control or make an anchor tag `runat="server"` unless you're doing something to it in your code behind.

```
<a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx?customer=" + "&CompanyName=" + Server.UrlEncode("abc#")) %>">wc</a>
```

Comment: actually I am using hyperlink control in my GridView control and doing some manipulation there. But even if it is outside the gridview then also it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the text property of the hyperlink control.

```
<asp:HyperLink   ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl ='<%= "~/Default.aspx?customer=" + "&CompanyName=" + Server.UrlEncode("abc#")%>' Text="wc" />
```

Comment: You don't need `Text` setting the inner content to "wc" works just the same

Comment: it is same ting as @hunter said, also you haven't answered the root problem

Comment: @Nits, This is totally different from what hunter said. He said to use an a tag, I said you were missing the text property of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

You also can set NavigateUrl property in code-behind file, in Page_Load event handler, for instance. It will work.

In the code-behind class:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                
            HyperLink2.NavigateUrl = "~/Default.aspx?customer=&CompanyName=" + Server.UrlEncode("abc#");                 
        }
```

And in markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Target="_new">wc  
</asp:HyperLink>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you mean to say it is working on your m/c( I am not getting the URL on hyperlink, when I am using this)

Comment: ok, try out full mark up of the page. Especially take a look at tag: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: also I want to point out that you shouldn't use Server.UrlEncode("abc#") in this case. You can replace this with "~/Default.aspx?customer=&CompanyName=abc#"

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= ... %>
```

doesn't work inside ASP.NET controls.

Alternatives:

- `<%# ... >` works in some cases in data-bound controls
- code-behind